# how long does a cake with avocado frosting last in the fridge?

Tags: cake, fresh, frosting

I am making a cake that I will frost with avocado frosting. For how many days can I keep cakes/cupcakes frosted with avocado frosting in the fridge?

I use this avocado frosting recipe from Alton Brown:

Ingredients:

8 ounces avocado meat, approximately 2 small to medium

2 teaspoons freshly squeezed lemon juice

1 pound powdered sugar, sifted

1/2 teaspoon lemon extract

Directions

Peel and pit the avocado. Place the avocado into the bowl of a stand mixer fitted with the whisk attachment along with the lemon juice and beat until lightened in color, approximately 2 to 3 minutes. Add the powdered sugar a little at a time and beat until smooth. Add the lemon extract and mix to combine. If not using right away, store in the refrigerator.

Comment: I'm not actually sure if this is a food safety question, or a discoloration question (although it's probably related to safety)

Comment: I don't think the cited duplicate question is valid. First, there is no mention of avocados or anything similar enough to make a reasonable conclusion about storage. Second, as @Erica brought up, it's not a food safety question but instead is asking about aesthetic qualities.